# render component based on selected item in array view

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, render

I'm working on a project where I need to provide a list of items from an array where one of the items is set to default. If a user clicks on another item then a check mark moves from the default item to the selected item.

For example if I have array `[default: "Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]`. Then if I click on Volvo it takes the default attribute. I've filtered out the array and updated it to the newly selected item. I'm having an issue displaying this on the view components once they've already rendered. My filter function is

```
selectItem(val){
  var currentDefault = this.state.vehicleList.find(function(element, index) {
    return element.default == true;
  });

  var currentVehicle = this.state.vehicleList.indexOf(currentDefault);
  var selectedItem = this.state.vehicleList.indexOf(val);

  if (currentVehicle != selectedItem){
    this.state.vehicleList[currentVehicle].default = false;
    this.state.vehicleList[selectedItem].default = true;
    this.state.pickedVehicle = this.state.vehicleList[selectedItem];
  } else {
    console.log('same vehicle');
  }   
}
```

Am I suppose to place the item in state to get it to change?

i'm adding the render function below.

```
_renderItem({item, key}) {

      const car = (<Icon name="car" size={16} color="grey" />)
      const bicycle = (<Icon name="bicycle" size={16} color="grey" />)
     color="black" />)
      const check = (<Icon name="check-square" size={30} color="green" />)



                        if (item.type == 'car'){
                            return (
                              <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.selectItem(item)} underlayColor={'transparent'}>
                                <LinearGradient key={key} style={{justifyContent: 'center', borderRadius: 30, width: 180, height: 120, alignSelf: 'center'}} colors={['#ff00ff', '#0066ff']}>
                                    {renderIf(item.default == true)(
                                            <Text key={key} style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', marginRight: 5}}> 
                                              {check}
                                             </Text>
                                        )}
                                    <View style={{alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', width: 40, height: 40, borderRadius: 60/2, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
                                        <Text style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}>
                                        {car} 
                                        </Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <Text style={{marginTop: 5, fontWeight: 'bold', marginTop: 5, color: 'white', fontSize: 12, alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',}}>
                                      {item.make} {item.model} {item.year}
                                    </Text>
                                    <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'white', fontSize: 12, alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',}}>
                                     {item.licensePlate} 
                                    </Text>
                                </LinearGradient>
                              </TouchableHighlight>
                              )
                          }
                          if (item.type == 'bicycle') {
                            return (
                                <LinearGradient key={key} style={{justifyContent: 'center', borderRadius: 30, width: 180, height: 120, alignSelf: 'center'}} colors={['#99cc00', '#000099']}>
                                      {renderIf(item.default == true)(
                                            <Text key={key} style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', marginRight: 5}}> 
                                              {check}
                                             </Text>
                                        )}
                                        <View style={{alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', width: 40, height: 40, borderRadius: 60/2, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
                                            <Text style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}>
                                            {bicycle} 
                                            </Text>
                                        </View>
                                        <Text style={{marginTop: 5, fontWeight: 'bold', marginTop: 5, color: 'white', fontSize: 12, alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',}}>
                                          {item.make} {item.model} {item.year}
                                        </Text>
                                        <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'white', fontSize: 12, alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',}}>
                                         {item.licensePlate} 
                                        </Text>
                                </LinearGradient>

                              )
                            }
```

how i'm adding the component

```
{this.state.vehicleList[index].default  && (
                                            <Text key={key} style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', marginRight: 5}}> 
                                              {check}
                                             </Text>
                                        )}
```

Comment: Yeah you need to use the state of these vehicles defaults while rendering. Can you share the code where you are rendering the components?

Comment: just updated it @Chandini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is a restriction on when to show the check icon next to the item, you can add that condition along with the Icon while rendering. For example you need to display Icon component based on that condition, you should add it like this.

```
{this.state.vehicleList[indexOfTheItem].default && (<Icon/>)}
```

The Icon will be rendered only if this.state.vehicleList[item].default is true

The component gets rendered again when the state changes. As you are updating the state of each vehicles default, you can use the corresponding vehicle's bool value as a condition next to it.

Comment: ok but how do I make the icon change from one item to another. The item.default is runs once when the view is first rendered. Can you provide more detail please?

Comment: Place the this.state.vehicleList[indexOfTheItem] condition and Icon next to every item, at any time only one of them will be default and will be in selected state. So for whichever item the state is true, the icon will be displayed next to that item only. Let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: ok so I added the code below but my checkmark doesn't move. @Chandini. Thank you again. This one is really holding me up and I feel like its something small i'm missing.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the correct value for the index of the item? And also whenever any item is clicked, you are updating the default states of all the items ryt?

Comment: Can you once debug selectItem function?

Comment: Yes I'm changing the default. I tested it out. I first filter out the array and find index of the current default item in the array. Then I take the value of the selected item and check to see if its the same as the current default. If not, then the default is changed from the old default to the new selected item. Only one item is defaulted in the array at a time. I've debugged this and it definitely works.

Comment: Okay. Can you place the condition inside the Text component and next to Icon like this.<Text key={key} style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', marginRight: 5}}> 
                                              {this.state.vehicleList[index].default  && check }
                                             </Text>

Comment: just tried that. copied your code. Still didn't update. Do you think its my selectionItem function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180771/discussion-between-chandini-and-kieran).